# Xcode ARMV application executable is missing

Tags: iphone, xcode, armv7, armv6

I need to change my "armv" before I can upload it. But how can I do it?
it says:

> iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required
>   architecture at least one of the following architecture(s) must be
>   present: armv6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add armv6 to your build settings. Also, make sure it is added to Valid Architectures. It should hopefully look something like this.

[image]